# How to select all rows that are related to satisfied condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I do not even knot how to ask what i need so I will demonstrate on data:

I have the following data in tblA:

[image]

the query need to result all rows where BMW 1 SERIES was involved in the accident with other cars, where the other car could also be BMW 1 SERIES. The End result should look like this:

[image]

Each accident has a ref number "AccRef" but there are multiple cars involved in an accident

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will query the first requirement of the `BMW 1 SERIES` rows:

`select * from ACCIDENTS where CarMake like '%BMW 1 SERIES%'`

Then you want to select the involved row with the same `AccRef`.
For best performances, use `inner join` on the same `AccRef` from the inner query mentioned above.

```
select ACC.* from ACCIDENTS ACC
inner join (
   select * from ACCIDENTS where CarMake like '%BMW 1 SERIES%'
) ACC_BMW 
on ACC.AccRef = ACC_BMW.AccRef
```

EDIT: I used the name table `ACCIDENTS` instead of your `tblA`

Answer (score 0):

Or also:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM accidents
WHERE accref IN (
  SELECT
    accref
  FROM accidents
  WHERE carmaker ='BMW 1 SERIES'
);
```

Comment: Can cause a performance issue.
I would not go with this solution as if you have a big table with a lot of data, that can be a disaster.

Comment: There are DBMSs that deal poorly with IN predicates, you're right,@EpsilonTal, and in that case,I also revert to an INNER JOIN - but with just the join column and not `*`, to make sure nothing is read/materialised that is not used.